# How trigger will work if using one table primary key to other table foreign key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, primary-key

I have two DB. One is remote DB and other is local DB. Both have three tables. I have created a trigger for orders table which will update/delete when there is any changes in remote db. I need to create trigger for other two tables ORd_detail and Releases. But i want to get values updated by using orderno in order table. How to modify the query to get verified when orderno is matched from two db.

1. Orders --> ID(PK) and OrderNo
2. Ord_Detail--> Ord_detail_ID(PK), ordersid(FK from orders table)
3. Releases--> Releases_id(PK), Ord_detail_ID(FK from ord_detail)

I have created a trigger for orders tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_order_locals
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON ORDERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
BEGIN
  -- Update or delete the corresponding row in the remote database
  IF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE ORDERS@local_link
    SET ID = :NEW.ID, ORDERNO = :NEW.ORDERNO, PONO = :NEW.PONO, ARCUSTO_ID = :NEW.ARCUSTO_ID, ORD_DATE = :NEW.ORD_DATE, ORD_BY = :NEW.ORD_BY, USERID = :NEW.USERID, DATE_TAKEN = :NEW.DATE_TAKEN, BILL_TO_ID = :NEW.BILL_TO_ID, SHIP_TO_ID = :NEW.SHIP_TO_ID, CUSER1 = :NEW.CUSER2, CUSER3 = :NEW.CUSER3, CUSER5 = :NEW.CUSER5, CUSER6 = :NEW.CUSER6, TIMESTAMP = :NEW.TIMESTAMP, FOB = :NEW.FOB, CHANGEUSER_ID = :NEW.CHANGEUSER_ID, TERMS_ID = :NEW.TERMS_ID, FREIGHT_ID = :NEW.FREIGHT_ID, FREE_FORM = :NEW.FREE_FORM, DISCOUNT = :NEW.DISCOUNT, CONTACT_ID = :NEW.CONTACT_ID, ECODE = :NEW.ECODE, EID = :NEW.EID, EDATE_TIME = :NEW.EDATE_TIME, ECOPY = :NEW.ECOPY, CURRENCY_ID = :NEW.CURRENCY_ID, TYPE = :NEW.TYPE, REV = :NEW.REV, OE_CONTROL = :NEW.OE_CONTROL, EPLANT_ID = :NEW.EPLANT_ID, EDI_855_CREATED = :NEW.EDI_855_CREATED, PRINT_COUNT = :NEW.PRINT_COUNT, PRINT_LAST_USER = :NEW.PRINT_LAST_USER, PRINT_LAST_DATE = :NEW.PRINT_LAST_DATE, WEB_ORDERS_ID = :NEW.WEB_ORDERS_ID, EDI_CHANGE_DATE = :NEW.EDI_CHANGE_DATE, WEB_CHANGE_DATE = :NEW.WEB_CHANGE_DATE, AGGREGATE_CALCULATED = :NEW.AGGREGATE_CALCULATED, INTER_CONSIGN = :NEW.INTER_CONSIGN, ARCUSTO_CREDIT_CARD_ID = :NEW.ARCUSTO_CREDIT_CARD_ID, DIVISION_ID = :NEW.DIVISION_ID, CUSER4 = :NEW.CUSER4, CRM_QUOTE_ID = :NEW.CRM_QUOTE_ID, ALT_DIVISION_ID = :NEW.ALT_DIVISION_ID, COMMENT1 = :NEW.COMMENT1, PAYMENT_TYPE = :NEW.PAYMENT_TYPE, EXT_COMMENT1 = :NEW.EXT_COMMENT1, ORD_LINE_DATE = :NEW.ORD_LINE_DATE, FREIGHT_CHARGE = :NEW.FREIGHT_CHARGE, FREIGHT_QUOTENO = :NEW.FREIGHT_QUOTENO, APPLY_FREIGHT_BOL_TO_PS = :NEW.APPLY_FREIGHT_BOL_TO_PS, CONTACT_ID2 = :NEW.CONTACT_ID2, CAMPAIGN_ID = :NEW.CAMPAIGN_ID, CRM_OPPORTUNITY_ID = :NEW.CRM_OPPORTUNITY_ID, FOB_THIRD_PARTY_ID = :NEW.FOB_THIRD_PARTY_ID, EDI_865_CREATED = :NEW.EDI_865_CREATED, DROP_SHIP_PO_ID = :NEW.DROP_SHIP_PO_ID, APPROVED = :NEW.APPROVED, APPROVAL_REQUIRED = :NEW.APPROVAL_REQUIRED, FREIGHT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = :NEW.FREIGHT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, IS_DRAFT = :NEW.IS_DRAFT, IS_MANUAL_OUTSOURCE = :NEW.IS_MANUAL_OUTSOURCE, IS_QUICK_ORDER = :NEW.IS_QUICK_ORDER, TAX_CALCULATED = :NEW.TAX_CALCULATED, SHIP_COMPLETE = :NEW.SHIP_COMPLETE, ACCRUED_FREIGHT = :NEW.ACCRUED_FREIGHT, ICT_MANUAL_SHIP_TO_ID = :NEW.ICT_MANUAL_SHIP_TO_ID, SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_ID = :NEW.SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_ID, SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_TOTAL_AMOUNT = :NEW.SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_TOTAL_AMOUNT, SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_PERCENT = :NEW.SO_DISCOUNT_TYPE_PERCENT, STATUS = :NEW.STATUS, PALLET_CHARGE = :NEW.PALLET_CHARGE, PALLET_CHARGE_SOURCE = :NEW.PALLET_CHARGE_SOURCE, USE_PALLET_CHARGE = :NEW.USE_PALLET_CHARGE, DIST_ROUTING_RULES_ID = :NEW.DIST_ROUTING_RULES_ID, DS_SOURCE = :NEW.DS_SOURCE
    WHERE ID = :OLD.ID AND ORDERNO = :OLD.ORDERNO;

  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM ORDERS@local_link
    WHERE ID = :OLD.ID AND ORDERNO = :OLD.ORDERNO;

  END IF;
  commit;
END;
/
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_orddetail_locals
AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE ON ORD_DETAIL
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
BEGIN
  -- Update or delete the corresponding row in the remote database
  IF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE ORD_DETAIL@local_link dst
    SET ID = :NEW.ID, ORDERS_ID = :NEW.ORDERS_ID, ARINVT_ID = :NEW.ARINVT_ID, ORD_DET_SEQNO = :NEW.ORD_DET_SEQNO, TOTAL_QTY_ORD = :NEW.TOTAL_QTY_ORD, CUMM_SHIPPED = :NEW.CUMM_SHIPPED, ONHOLD = :NEW.ONHOLD, TAX_CODE_ID = :NEW.TAX_CODE_ID, MISC_ITEM = :NEW.MISC_ITEM, COMMENT1 = :NEW.COMMENT1, UNIT_PRICE = :NEW.UNIT_PRICE, SALESPEOPLE_ID = :NEW.SALESPEOPLE_ID, COMM_PCT = :NEW.COMM_PCT, PRICE_PER_1000 = :NEW.PRICE_PER_1000, LIST_UNIT_PRICE = :NEW.LIST_UNIT_PRICE, DISCOUNT = :NEW.DISCOUNT, ECODE = :NEW.ECODE, EID = :NEW.EID, EDATE_TIME = :NEW.EDATE_TIME, ECOPY = :NEW.ECOPY, EPLANT_ID = :NEW.EPLANT_ID, COST_OBJECT_ID = :NEW.COST_OBJECT_ID, COST_OBJECT_SOURCE = :NEW.COST_OBJECT_SOURCE, UNIT = :NEW.UNIT, UOM_FACTOR = :NEW.UOM_FACTOR, GLACCT_ID = :NEW.GLACCT_ID, DOCKID = :NEW.DOCKID, LINEFEED = :NEW.LINEFEED, RESERVELOCATION = :NEW.RESERVELOCATION, KBTRIGGER = :NEW.KBTRIGGER, AGGREGATE_DISCOUNT = :NEW.AGGREGATE_DISCOUNT, CUST_CUM_START = :NEW.CUST_CUM_START, LAST_RECEIPT_QTY = :NEW.LAST_RECEIPT_QTY, LAST_RECEIPT_DATE = :NEW.LAST_RECEIPT_DATE, RMA_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.RMA_DETAIL_ID, REF_CODE_ID = :NEW.REF_CODE_ID, FAB_QTY = :NEW.FAB_QTY, RAW_MT_QTY = :NEW.RAW_MT_QTY, FAB_START_DATE = :NEW.FAB_START_DATE, FAB_END_DATE = :NEW.FAB_END_DATE, CONTAINERS = :NEW.CONTAINERS, FROM_SALES_OPTION = :NEW.FROM_SALES_OPTION, SHIP_TO_ID_FROM = :NEW.SHIP_TO_ID_FROM, IN_TRANSIT_WORKORDER_ID = :NEW.IN_TRANSIT_WORKORDER_ID, IN_TRANSIT_PARTNO_ID = :NEW.IN_TRANSIT_PARTNO_ID, IS_DROP_SHIP = :NEW.IS_DROP_SHIP, IS_MAKE_TO_ORDER = :NEW.IS_MAKE_TO_ORDER, MFG_QUAN = :NEW.MFG_QUAN, PO_INFO = :NEW.PO_INFO, MAKE_TO_ORDER_PS_TICKET_DTL_ID = :NEW.MAKE_TO_ORDER_PS_TICKET_DTL_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID = :NEW.CAMPAIGN_ID, CTP = :NEW.CTP, CRM_QUOTE_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.CRM_QUOTE_DETAIL_ID, SALES_OPTION_CHOICE_ID = :NEW.SALES_OPTION_CHOICE_ID, CUSER1 = :NEW.CUSER1, CUSER2 = :NEW.CUSER2, CUSER3 = :NEW.CUSER3, REBATE_PARAMS_ID = :NEW.REBATE_PARAMS_ID, PHANTOM_ORD_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.PHANTOM_ORD_DETAIL_ID, PHANTOM_PTSPER = :NEW.PHANTOM_PTSPER, HIDE = :NEW.HIDE, OUTSOURCE_PO_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.OUTSOURCE_PO_DETAIL_ID, LOT_CHARGE_ARINVT_ID = :NEW.LOT_CHARGE_ARINVT_ID, STANDARD_ID = :NEW.STANDARD_ID, DIVISION_ID = :NEW.DIVISION_ID, AKA_KIND = :NEW.AKA_KIND, MSDS_UPLOAD = :NEW.MSDS_UPLOAD, SHIPHOLD = :NEW.SHIPHOLD, MILK_RUN_LOCATIONS_ID = :NEW.MILK_RUN_LOCATIONS_ID, LOT_CHARGE_ORD_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.LOT_CHARGE_ORD_DETAIL_ID, AUTO_INVOICE = :NEW.AUTO_INVOICE, C_PO_MISC_ID = :NEW.C_PO_MISC_ID, MISC_ITEMNO = :NEW.MISC_ITEMNO, SAMPLE = :NEW.SAMPLE, PHANTOM_DTL_MODIFIED = :NEW.PHANTOM_DTL_MODIFIED, BOGO_ORD_DETAIL_ID = :NEW.BOGO_ORD_DETAIL_ID, BOGO_AR_DISCOUNT_TIERS_ID = :NEW.BOGO_AR_DISCOUNT_TIERS_ID, BOGO_EXCEPTION = :NEW.BOGO_EXCEPTION, PRICE_BOOK_ID = :NEW.PRICE_BOOK_ID, PRICE_BOOK_PRICE_TYPE_ID = :NEW.PRICE_BOOK_PRICE_TYPE_ID, NEW_SEQUENCE_COLUMN = :NEW.NEW_SEQUENCE_COLUMN
    WHERE dst.ID = :NEW.ID 
    OR dst.ORDERS_ID = (SELECT ORDERNO FROM ORDERS@local_link WHERE ID = :NEW.ORDERS_ID);
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM ORD_DETAIL@local_link
    WHERE ID = :OLD.ID AND ORDERS_ID = :OLD.ORDERS_ID;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

I have created trigger for ord_detail. But not working. Please verify and correct the code

Comment: There's quite a problem having autonomous_transaction in triggers unless they only write to some log files to indicate the progress of some process. What if the autonomous_transaction commits, but the transaction that fired the trigger is rolled back? Wouldn't this lead to inconsistencies?

Answer (score 2):

What does "not working" mean?

As `TRG_ORDDETAIL_LOCALS` is an autonomous transaction, it requires either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, and you have neither.

---

Anyway, I'd suggest you to consider abandoning this model and switch to something else, for example **materialized views** you'd refresh e.g. `on commit`:

> ([Refreshing materialized views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/refreshing-materialized-views.html#GUID-587D67C7-CD96-44CA-8B3B-597C39247F31))
>
> A materialized view can be refreshed automatically using the ON COMMIT method. Therefore, whenever a transaction commits which has updated the tables on which a materialized view is defined, those changes are automatically reflected in the materialized view. The advantage of using this approach is you never have to remember to refresh the materialized view. (...)

Comment: Thankyou for your reply @littlefoot. So my query is correct apart from that commit/rollback?

Comment: I don't have your tables to try it myself, but - at the first glance, it looks OK.